# Using Array of Dictionary to populate tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an array of dictionary created as below:

```
    var menuItems = [["Image" : "bars_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Bars"], ["Image" : "clubs_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Clubs"]]
```

I've created a custom table view cell and populating the table view cell as below:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell: MenuTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuCell") as MenuTableViewCell

     let dict = menuItems[indexPath.row]
     cell.menuImage.image = UIImage(named: dict["Image"]!)
     cell.menuTitle.text = dict["Title"]

     return cell
    }
```

When debugging the src code, after executing below line, "dict" is nil.

```
let dict = menuItems[indexPath.row]
```

I am not able to make out what's the issue.

Comment: Does the program crash? Any error messages?

Comment: @alkku, as dict value is nil, on the next line its crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code is looking for a key of `Image`:

```
cell.menuImage.image = UIImage(named: dict["Image"]!)
```

But `menuItems` is using `Image:` as the key:

```
var menuItems = [["Image:" : "bars_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Bars"], ["Image:" : "clubs_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Clubs"]]
```

I suspect you did not intend to include the colon in the key:

```
var menuItems = [["Image" : "bars_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Bars"], ["Image" : "clubs_icon_main_page", "Title" : "Clubs"]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Its a typo. I updated my question. But the problem is in the line "let dict = menuItems[indexPath.row]"

Comment: @Satyam Obviously, given what you provided in your question, that's not possible that `dict` would be `nil`. It's possible that the debugger is confused (so programmatically `println` the value, don't rely on the debugger). And `println` three things: 1. `println(indexPath.row)`? 2. `println(menuItems)` (to make sure something didn't change it or mess up the values); and 3 `println(dict)`.

Comment: indexPath.row is printing 0 and 1. menuItems is printing the whole array. dict value is being printed as {}

Comment: Clearly there's something else going on here. Perhaps you can create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload it somewhere where we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your array of Dictionary is implementing with **Image:** key and your code is using **Image** without **:** in key

Comment: Thanks. Its a typo. I updated my question. The problem is in the line "let dict = menuItems[indexPath.row]"

Comment: Did you verify if the indexPath.row contains in array?  >> like `if( menuItems.count > indexPath.row) { do your logic... }`

Comment: @VictorCarvalhoTavernari Shouldn't that crash if you try to access outside the array range?

Comment: No, work with collections is fragile, if you try access outside the range your app will crash. Take attention when work with collections.